# How to insert a input variable into a print statement?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and need some help. I'm not sure if my question is the right terminology but I cant figure it out. I've tried .format f-string but I cant get it to work. The codes purpose is to ask a user to fill in a story. Edit: Forgot to Add character input. Forgot to add issue. Fixed Ty kind stranger!

This is the code

```
#Purpose: Ask a user to fill in a story 
    def main():

 character = input("What do you want your character name to be?")
setting = input("Where do you want your story to take place?")
time = input("What year does the story take place?")
meaning = input("What is character doing?")
meaningTwo = input("What is the meaning for the characters actions?")
print(f"For character name you input {character}. For setting you said {setting}. For the year 
  you said {time}. Your character is {meaning}. The meaning for the characters actions is 
  {meaningTwo}.") 
 question = input("Is this correct (yes or no)") 
 if(question == "yes"): 
  print("Alright here is your story:")
  print("Unfinished Story")
 else: 

  print("Ok Goodbye")

 main()
```

Comment: Where is ```character``` variable ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "can't get it to work". Your [mre] should indicate what output you're getting versus what you're expecting. Your example's formatting also needs to be correct; as-is, with the messed up indentation, we can't just paste your code into an IDE and see your issue.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on how indentation works in python, I'm not sure if it didn't paste right or this is how the original code is, but what you've posted has quite a few indentation problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

EDIT: After comments...

There were a few things to change here. You didn't have the character variable set to anything so that threw an error - that's why I added a character line below that takes user input.

In the print line you had, it was too long - i.e. going over one line - so that caused some errors. For long strings like this you can wrap them in triple quotes, then it doesn't matter if they go over one line.

Also, watch out for indentation errors. There should be an indent (hit tab) after an if or else statement.

```
def main():
    setting = input("Where do you want your story to take place?")
    time = input("What year does the story take place?")
    character = input("What is your character's name?")
    meaning = input("What is character doing?")
    meaningTwo = input("What is the meaning for the characters actions?")
    print(f"""For character name you input {character}. For setting you said {setting}. For the year 
      you said {time}. Your character is {meaning}. The meaning for the characters actions is 
      {meaningTwo}.""") 
    question = input("Is this correct (yes or no)") 
    if question == "yes": 
        print("Alright here is your story:")
        print("Unfinished Story")
    else: 
        print("Ok Goodbye")

main()
```

Comment: "just code" answers seldom help. Could you explain what was wrong? BTW, `if` is not a function and doesn't need parentheses. So `if(question == "yes"):` should be written as `if question == "yes":`.

Answer (score 0):

Your character variable does not exist. You need to declare it.

Also, your code is formatted in a funny way. If that is how you wrote it, then another problem is that your "main" function is empty. Remove the indent on the line that declares the function main and then indent all the other code, except for main(), so your code is in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```py
print('''For character name you input {name}. For setting you said {setting}. For the year you said {time}. Your character is {meaning}. The meaning for the characters actions is {meaning2}.'''.format(name='character', setting=setting, time=time, meaning=meaning, meaning2=meaningTwo))
```

We can insert it using assigned keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please don't add HTML tags in answers, check out how stackoverflow's markdown works for [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).